# Outlook Macro for a Trickle send with a bulk delay? Is this possible?

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-office, outlook-2010

Can anyone help me with this?

I'm having a lot of trouble getting this Bulk message delay macro to work exactly how I want it to, I've been trying in my spare time at work for the last month and thought it was about time I asked the experts.

The basic principle is I want to be able to turn on my Bulkdelay macro (that's already in place and works great) and for it to delay my messages to the specified time ***AND THEN*** when they do go out, they go out in three-second intervals, Like a trickle send. At the minute I can do one or the other but not both!

To change the code from a standard bulk delay to a progressive "trickle" send you only need to edit on thing from the below code.... "0" to however many seconds delay you want between emails. (See code snippet below)

```
'On the next line enter the number of seconds to delay messages for if you want all messages to be delayed for a fixed amount of time.  Enter 0 if you want to be prompted for the date/time to delay until.'
intDelay = 0
```

I'm running this macro alongside a simple Bulksendall macro that basically sends everything from a specified folder. So I'd turn on the Bulkdelay, set my time, then hit my Bulksendall macro and the emails send but sit in my outbox until the time I set, Works perfectly.

Basically want is a combo of the two, so a delay for 08:12AM for example and then when the 50 emails go out they go out 3 seconds apart! I don't know if its possible, I got the code I'm using and others I've tried from this link - https://techniclee.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/setting-a-bulk-message-delay/

The full code I'm currently using is below, it's in two parts. Next is another code I have tried running alongside the original code to get it working, Finally is my BulkSendAll code -

```
Dim clsBDM As BulkDelayManager

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set clsBDM = New BulkDelayManager
End Sub

Private Sub Application_Quit()
    Set clsBDM = Nothing
End Sub

Sub ToggleBDM()
    clsBDM.Toggle
End Sub
```

---

```
Private bolBulkDelay As Boolean, _
        datBulkDelaySendAt As Date, _
        intDelay As Integer
Private WithEvents olkApp As Outlook.Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    'On the next line enter the number of seconds to delay messages for if you want all messages to be delayed for a fixed amount of time.  Enter 0 if you want to be prompted for the date/time to delay until.'
    intDelay = 0
    bolBulkDelay = False
    Set olkApp = Outlook.Application
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set olkApp = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub Toggle()
    bolBulkDelay = Not bolBulkDelay
    If intDelay = 0 Then
        If bolBulkDelay Then
            datBulkDelaySendAt = InputBox("Enter the date/time that messages will be delayed until.", "Set Bulk Delay Time", Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yy hh:nn AMPM"))
            If Not IsDate(datBulkDelaySendAt) Then
                bolBulkDelay = False
            End If
        End If
    End If
    msgbox "Bulk Delaying is now " & IIf(bolBulkDelay, " on.", " off."), vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Bulk Delay Manager"
End Sub

Private Sub olkApp_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    If bolBulkDelay Then
        If intDelay = 0 Then
            Item.DeferredDeliveryTime = datBulkDelaySendAt
        Else
            Item.DeferredDeliveryTime = DateAdd("s", intDelay, Now)
        End If
        Item.Save
    End If
End Sub
```

I have also tried a combo of the above code and the code below to try and fix the problem but doesn't seem to work either? Once I use the "SendAtSpecificTime" macro it seems to cancel out the "Bulkdelay" macro.

```
    Sub SendAtSpecificTime()
    Const SCRIPT_NAME = "Send at Specific Time"
    Dim olkMsg As Outlook.MailItem, strSnd As String, datSnd As Date, intCnt As Integer
    strSnd = InputBox("Enter the date and time you want the messages sent.", SCRIPT_NAME)
    If IsDate(strSnd) Then
        datSnd = strSnd
        For intCnt = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count To 1 Step -1
            Set olkMsg = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(intCnt)
            olkMsg.DeferredDeliveryTime = datSnd
            olkMsg.Send
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "You did not enter a valid date/time.  Operation cancelled.", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, SCRIPT_NAME
    End If
    Set olkMsg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Finally here is the code I'm using for the Bulksendall

```
Public Sub SendDrafts()

Dim lDraftItem As Long
Dim myOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myFolders As Outlook.Folders
Dim myDraftsFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

'Send all items in the "Drafts" folder that have a "To" address filled in.

'Setup Outlook
Set myOutlook = Outlook.Application
Set myNameSpace = myOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myFolders = myNameSpace.Folders
'Set Draft Folder.
Set myDraftsFolder = myFolders("john.Doe@Example.co.uk").Folders("eShotOut")
'Loop through all Draft Items
For lDraftItem = myDraftsFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1

'Check for "To" address and only send if "To" is filled in.
If Len(Trim(myDraftsFolder.Items.Item(lDraftItem).To)) > 0 Then
'Send Item
On Error Resume Next
myDraftsFolder.Items.Item(lDraftItem).Send
On Error GoTo 0
End If
Next lDraftItem
'Clean-up
Set myDraftsFolder = Nothing
Set myNameSpace = Nothing
Set myOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

I'm not really educated in VBA or any coding for that matter, everything I've done in Outlook and on Excel in the past has purely been from research on google and online forums, this is the first time I've had to post so hopefully someone out there can help! Any input at all is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust the delay in `Item.DeferredDeliveryTime` so each mail gets a delay larger than the previous like this.

```
' In the ThisOutlookSession" module
Private bulkSendDelayCount As Long

Private bolBulkDelay As Boolean
Private datBulkDelaySendAt As Date
Private intDelay As Long

'Private WithEvents olkApp As Outlook.Application

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
'Private Sub olkApp_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    If InStr(Item.Subject, "test") Then

        If bolBulkDelay Then

            'Debug.Print "bulkSendDelayCount: " & bulkSendDelayCount

            If intDelay = 0 Then
                Item.DeferredDeliveryTime = datBulkDelaySendAt
            Else
                Item.DeferredDeliveryTime = DateAdd("s", bulkSendDelayCount * intDelay, Now)
                bulkSendDelayCount = bulkSendDelayCount + 1
            End If
            Item.Save
            Debug.Print "Date format does not include seconds."
            Debug.Print "Item.DeferredDeliveryTime: " & Item.DeferredDeliveryTime
        End If

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize_test()

    ' Date format uses 00 for seconds
    ' Reliable delay in minutes, 60 second increments

    ' If for example you try 30,
    '  there should be 2 sends per minute at the same time.
    ' Three seconds should mean 10 sends per minute at the same time.
    intDelay = 30
    bolBulkDelay = True
    bulkSendDelayCount = 0
    'Set olkApp = outlook.Application

End Sub
```